# Confused about HTML Layout approach

Tags: html

**Newbie Alert!**  I'm asking this question, because management is in a hurry!  They want seven pages done by yesterday.  So I need some advice, quickly.

I have requirements to create a div that looks similar to the following picture:

[image]

This question is about Layout.  I'm using the standard HTML dropdowns.

**First:**  I started off by using 1 row with 4 columns.  But then I found it difficult to align my labels (black squares on the left) with the dropdowns.

**Second:**  Then I thought maybe I should create 7 rows, each with 4 columns, so I could better align the contents of each row.

**Third:**  But given that I have to add the Help "?" button with the text, I started wondering if I should use an in-line-block.  **Also, by this time, I think I may be making the code more complicated than it needs to be.**

So, what I am asking is:

**What is the simplest and (or) most effective method to create a layout like this?**

Perhaps, I need only 2 columns; one for the labels, Help buttons, and dropdowns, and the second column for the text boxes.  **My idea is that if I'm trying too hard, I'm probably doing it wrong!**  How would you do this?

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: You need to give us some idea what libraries you're working with. If it's entirely home-brew, show some markup and ask more specific questions. It's too broad as it is. Frankly, a simple table seems right. You appear to be dealing with tabular data, after all.

Comment: For me those are 5 vertical `div`s (yes, the OR gets its own vertical separation div) and each element inside is placed into a `div` with fixed height.  Everything (but the OR) is centre aligned.

Comment: This is straight up HTML.  No libraries!  I'm simply creating the layout "with no functionality until database folks can give me something to work with."  I have started creating (learning) my own style sheets.  Strictly, HTML and eventually JavaScript.

Comment: I will recommend you to use bootstrap, it is very easy to create this form

Comment: Image does not load for me.

Comment: @domdom - Try this link:   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8tC1ewFw3KlSWRzN3A5LU9XOVE